# for db recover process testing, unable obtain the query o/p using shell script

Tags: oracle, rman

I have written shell script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
#shell script for recovery testing
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/rman target/ <<EOF >rman.log
        shutdown immediate;
        startup mount;
        run
        {
                recover database;
        }
        sql 'alter database open read only';
exit;
EOF

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus '/as sysdba' <<_EOF1_ >sql.log
        spool '/home/oracle/test1.log'
        select * from hr.employees;
        spool off;
exit;
_EOF1_
```

, but unable to obtain the spool the output from sql query, how to solve the issue?

Comment: Describe your problem more in detail. What's the expected output? What does it mean "unable to obtain"? What's the error you encountered?

Comment: First part, EOF to EOF work, but second part _EOF1_, uanble to run

Comment: while run the script, RMAN part sucessfully completed with error: ./rmanrecover.sh: line 19: warning: here-document at line 13 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `_EOF1_'), and does not run the sqlplus part, but while the rman part is written in one script, and same sqlplus part is written in other script and call the sqlplus script from rman script the sucessfully works.

Comment: Don't post clarifications in the comments, but rather edit the question to contain that information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your code. It should work. I tested it:

```
$ sqlplus '/as sysdba' <<_EOF1_ >sql.log
        spool '/home/oracle/test1.log'
        select * from dual;
        spool off;
exit;
_EOF1_
```

**Output**

```
$ cat sql.log 

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Nov 6 15:18:42 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL> 
D
-
X

SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

**Output 2**

```
$ cat /home/oracle/test1.log 
SQL>         select * from dual;

D                                                                               
-                                                                               
X                                                                               

SQL>         spool off;
```

There are two options to acomplish your goal. You use both in one. Any reasons for that?

**Option 1**

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF > /dev/null
spool test.out
select * from dual;
spool off
EOF
```

Output

```
$ cat test.out 
SQL> select * from dual;

D                                                                               
-                                                                               
X                                                                               

SQL> spool off
```

**Option 2**

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF > test.out 
> select * from dual;
> EOF
```

Output

```
$ cat test.out 

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Nov 6 15:12:05 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> 
D
-
X

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```